# Record audio from line-in with JAVA

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Lets say I have a piece of audio playing and I want to record it. So I connect a male to male cable from the line out to line in. So there is no mic.

Is there a way to record this and put it into a .wav file and store it with Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826169/record-voice-with-java

Comment: I have the same question did you found a solution :) ?

Answer (score 1):

The following article was the accepted answer to another question

[Capturing Audio with Java](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CapturingAudiowithJavaSoundAPI.htm)
It's too much content to describe here, I hate just posting a link, but...

Comment: Not sure if that will work though... he talks about voice recording so I assume he's using a mic. I have no mic but just a cable with sound coming through. Also I am playing sound at the same time so not sure if that would cause some issue.