# Reading audio through microphone Using java

Tags: java

How to read the audio through microphone using Java? Can anyone explain?

1. please tell the Classes we need use.
2. or else give the link for online reference

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you look for things that the java API can do always look first in the offical Oracle tutorials. There are a lot of them and they are, most of the time, a good starting point.

For you problem look at this one :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Java tutorials has a section on it:
`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html`

If you want a quick solution, have a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705581/java-sound-api-capturing-microphone) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826169/record-voice-with-java).