# how to listen to microphone in "always listening mode"

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am trying to implement "always listening" java program which listens from microphone for hotword like "ok,google" or "alexa".

I found many examples where it listens to microphone for few seconds.
[Record voice with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826169/record-voice-with-java)

However my use case is to listen all the time until hot-word is detected.

Any pointers?

Comment: You just keep on reading from the line.

Comment: your hot question is to recognize the hot word so you are asking about speech recognition - you are far away first you need to learn to read the "datas"

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4 this link provides a tutorial about how to install and use it.

Also an old tutorialon youtube about how to do a first use of it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeqtLrcOogs